# Shell script for post-commit hook gives - Not a git repository error

Tags: git, shell, virtualenv, githooks

I have written a post-commit hook which requires creating the virtual environment for the python script to run when a commit happens.

Following is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Teamcity-build trigger

echo "Executing post-commit hook"

BASEDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
VENV=venv
ACTIVATE=$VENV/bin/activate
STATUS=false
CIDIR=teamcity

# Username
machine=$(uname -n)

echo "Notifying Teamcity Server to execute a Build on " $machine
# Logic to check if commit is done or merged to a particular branch / master branch

cd $BASEDIR
# Change directory to parent directory, since current directory is `.git/hooks/`
cd ../..
# Go in teamcity directory
cd $CIDIR

# Check if venv folder exists, if it does not then create it
if [ ! -d "$VENV" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $VENV doesn't exist.
  virtualenv -p python $VENV
  STATUS=true
fi

# Source virtual environment
source $ACTIVATE

# Install required dependencies if not yet installed
if [ "$STATUS" = true ]; then
    # if status is true, means need to install all the required libraries
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
fi

# check current git branch
# $(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD)
if [ "$BRANCH" = "rahul" ]; then
    # if branch is master, then only proceed.
    # Start processing teamcity jobs
    python last_dir_processed.py
else
    echo "Current Branch $BRANCH, Nothing to execute."
fi

# Deactivate virtual environment
deactivate
```

On line 43,

```
BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

the script tries to know name of the current branch.

But it gives error as:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '.git'
```

I chacked the folder path with pwd command before that line and it shows `.git` folder exists.

Also, When I ran following command manualy, it worked:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

This gave me a current branch name.

**EDIT:** Following is my directory structure:

```
--root_dir
    --teamcity
        -last_dir_processed.py
    --.git
        --hooks
            -post-commit
```

So, ideally the script should execute properly, but still it gives the error. Not sure what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure, set [`GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations) in order to be sure any `git` command runs in the right context:

```
cd ../..
GIT_DIR=$(pwd)/.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=$(pwd)
```

Comment: Best to set them with `export` commands in most cases, although for this particular one, we can make an exception since if they're *not* in the environment, we don't need to *put* them there.

Comment: @torek I agree. This was just for testing if that makes any difference.